# Python: increasing array indexes

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have a random csv file containing random numbers, comma separated. I'm doing some iteration, in order to filter data

```
if (int(row[0]) + i == int(row[1])) and int(row[1]) + i == int(row[2]) and int(row[2]) + i == int(row[3]) and int(row[3]) + i == int(row[4]):
    do something
elif (int(row[0]) + i == int(row[1])) and int(row[1]) + i == int(row[2]) and int(row[2]) + i == int(row[3]):
    do something
```

The If statements are so much more than that. My code obviously works perfectly, since there's nothing special about it.

I just wish to find a way to do what I'm doing without having to type

`if row[0] and row[1] and row[2] and..`.

say the maximum is row[4] as shown in the example above,basically, i want to something, like a recursive function to do:

```
for n in range of 0 to 4
    if row[n] +i == row[n+1]:
        do something
        row[n] == row[n-1]
           if row[n-1] ...
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this, I hope my question is clear. I think this is a similar [question in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303362/increasing-array-with-rows).

The part that I don't really know how to do, is how to get rid of `and`, I mean if i should write `if... and ...and` then I could just copy paste and do what I was doing, I want a better solution, if it exists.

If a solution exists, I'd prefer if it's a recursive one, because I am working hard to get rid of loops in my code.

Comment: `if all(int(row[n])+i==int(row[n+1]) for n in range(4)): ...`

Comment: "If a solution exists, I'd prefer if it's a recursive one, because I am working hard to get rid of loops in my code." *Why*? Recursion is not one of python's strong suits. Generally you'd want to go the *other* way: remove recursion and replace it with an iterative approach.

Comment: Are you trying to see if everything in a particular row has the same value?

Comment: Are you primarily looking for a solution for checking **a particular length of row values**, like your example with 4, or **to find out how many values in a row have this property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare with a `range`:

```
if [int(x) for x in row[0:4]] == range(int(row[0]), int(row[0]) + 4 * i, i):
```

The right-hand side will be integers in the range from `row[0]` through `row[0] + 3 * i`, in increments of `i`.

If you're always treating these rows as integers, it might be simpler to convert your row into a `list` of `int` beforehand:

```
row = [int(x) for x in row]
```

So that you can write the condition more simply:

```
if row[0:4] == range(row[0], row[0] + 4 * i, i):
```

Comment: `if [int(x) for x in row[0:4]] == range(int(row[0]), int(row[0]) + 4 * i, i):  `